# Plotly: make width of boxplots fill gaps between categories

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django, plotly

I have the following Plotly plot right now. But as you can see, the boxplots are squished width-wise and after a lot of googling it seems that it is an intended behaviour from Plotly which "reserves" space for every category the total amount of boxplots in the plot (i hope that was clear).

[image]

But this is pretty illegible. Ideally I'd want the boxplots to take the whole space for every category. I'm using Django 4.1 with Plotly 2.26 in Javascript, so that the plotting can be faster rather than doing everything in the backend.

Here is a snippet of the data:

```
                                                    sample_1  ...  sample_2
2023-08-16|run1                                     NaN       ...  NaN
2023-08-16|run2                                     NaN       ...  NaN
2023-08-18|run3                                     NaN       ...  NaN
2023-08-18|run4                                     NaN       ...  NaN
2023-08-18|run5                                     8530990.0 ...  NaN
2023-08-21|run6                                     NaN       ...  10346463.0
```

Here is the code that i use for that plot:

```py
    plot_data = plot_data.sort_index()

    for index in plot_data.index:
        report_date, project_name = index.split("|")
        cleaned_data = plot_data.loc[[index]].transpose().dropna().values.flatten().tolist()
        trace = {
            "x0": report_date,
            "y": sorted(cleaned_data),
            "name": project_name,
            "type": "box",
            "marker": {
                "line": {
                    "outlierwidth": 2
                }
            },
            "boxpoints": 'suspectedoutliers',
        }
        traces.append(trace)

    return json.dumps(traces)
```

What is returned is then passed to the template under the `plot` variable name.

```js
<div id="plot-div"></div>

<script>
var plot_data = JSON.parse("{{plot|escapejs}}");
var layout = {
    xaxis: {
        type: "category",
        title: "Date",
    },
    showlegend: false,
    boxmode: "group",
    boxgroupgap: 0.1,
    boxgap: 0.1,
};
Plotly.newPlot("plot-div", plot_data, layout, {responsive: true});
</script>
```

I have found other people with the same "issue" that I have but I couldn't find a good solution. Thanks for your help in advance.